# Cannot connect to a specific wifi on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, 20.04

I have a strange issue about Wifi connectivity. My home has two wifi modems, F1 and F2 for each floor. My Ubuntu version was 18.04 and I want to upgrade to 20.04, but have to upgrade to 19.10 first. Then when I finally upgraded to 20.04, I cannot connect to F2 wifi, it keeps connecting but never success. Connecting to F1 works well.

All I remember is when I was at Ubuntu 19.10, I use the F2 wifi to run command for upgrading to 20.04. Hence, when I unplug the F2 wifi modem and replug, my laptop can connect to it but when I disconnect it or restart the computer, the issue persists.

If you need any information for investigation, just tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi!  I would add these related links, can hopefully be of help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos    And,   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278694/wifi-connects-but-pages-dont-load/1281120#1281120   //Best wishes

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.  I may have resolved it by myself or the recent Ubuntu updates has fixed it. I will refer to your link when necessary.

Comment: I tried all the following solutions, but none worked for me except the one posted here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1277071/35310 I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Network logs should be sent to /var/log/syslog

You can perhaps try monitoring the log using:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Then attempting to connect again.

Optionally you can also share the log (tail -n40 /var/log/syslog) and perhaps someone can help further.

Answer (score -1):

**On router settings** (go to 192.168.0.1 or your router address):

Go through the setup wizard and also changed authentication method to WPA2-PSK.

[Dlink administration SCreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATvwv.png) .

---

**On Ubuntu 20.04**:

Assume that the wireless network interface is `wlp5s0`.

Edit file:

```
sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add following lines:

```
auto wlp5s0
iface wlan0 inet static
```

Save and close the file, then:

```
ifconfig wlp5s0 down
ifconfig wlp5s0 up
```

Comment: `iface wlan0 inet static` won't work without setting a static address, etc. And what is `wlan0` if the interface is `wlp5s0`? So it is a crap answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 the crap maybe was unnecessarily.. It can't be easy all the time to know each little detail, (Just wanted to add that)  Not to sound offensive;Sorry If I did:  //Regards